# Equivalent of RxJs Observables in C#

Tags: c#

In RxJS , you have Observables. Do you have any equivalent built-in functionality in .NET that does the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Rx.NET:

> The Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous
>   and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style
>   query operators. Using Rx, developers represent asynchronous data
>   streams with Observables, query asynchronous data streams using LINQ
>   operators, and parameterize the concurrency in the asynchronous data
>   streams using Schedulers. Simply put, Rx = Observables + LINQ +
>   Schedulers.

[The Reactive Extensions for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive).  Note that the [IObservable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netcore-3.1) is part of .NET Standard, but the extensions that add all the reactive operators are in a separate [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/).